# Fade in and Out Youtube Video with JavaScript API

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube, youtube-api

I am trying to fade in an iframe containing a YouTube video when the video starts, and fade it out when it ends (before it shows the still image with the red player button in the middle). Right now, the video is stuck at opacity: 0. It's like the code isn't detecting the start of the video. Here is my code ([most of it is from Google](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Getting_Started)):

HTML

```
    <iframe id="player" 
        width="560" height="315" 
        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-K2fShrbvfY?modestbranding=1&rel=0&controls=0&enablejsapi" 
        frameborder="0" allowfullscreen
    ></iframe>

    <script>
  // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
  //    after the API code downloads.
  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }

  // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.style.opacity = 1; 
    event.target.playVideo();
  }

  // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
  //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
  //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
  var done = false;
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
        event.target.style.opacity = 0; 
        setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
        done = true;
    }
  }
  function stopVideo() {
    player.stopVideo();
  }
</script>
```

CSS

```
#player{
opacity: 0;
transition: all 1s;
```

}

I also tried `document.getElementById('player').style.opacity = 1;` instead of `event.target.style.opacity = 1;` , but it still does not fade the video in.

New code, thanks to help from below. However, I still get the YouTube water mark and the still image at the end.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <style>
          #player {
              display:  none;
          }
      </style>
  </head>
  <body>
      <!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
      <div id="player"></div>

      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>

      <script>

          // create youtube player
          var player;
          function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
              player = new YT.Player('player', {
                  height: '390',
                  width: '640',
                  videoId: '0Bmhjf0rKe8',
                  playerVars: {
                      modestbranding: 1,
                      rel: 0,
                      controls: 0,
                      showinfo: 0
                  },
                  events: {
                      'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                  }
              });
          }

          // autoplay video
          function onPlayerReady(event) {
              $('#player').fadeIn(function() {
                  event.target.playVideo();
              });
          }

          // when video ends
          function onPlayerStateChange(event) {        
              if (event.data === 0) {          
                  $('#player').fadeOut();
              }
          }

          </script>
      </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Try this***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <style>
          #player {
              display:  none;
          }
      </style>
  </head>
  <body>
      <!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
      <div id="player"></div>

      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>

      <script>

          // create youtube player
          var player;
          function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
              player = new YT.Player('player', {
                  height: '390',
                  width: '640',
                  videoId: '0Bmhjf0rKe8',
                  playerVars: {
                      modestbranding: 1
                  },
                  events: {
                      'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                  }
              });
          }

          // autoplay video
          function onPlayerReady(event) {
              $('#player').fadeIn(function() {
                  event.target.playVideo();
              });
          }

          // when video ends
          function onPlayerStateChange(event) {        
              if (event.data === 0) {          
                  $('#player').fadeOut();
              }
          }

          </script>
      </body>
  </html>
```

**However**

You cannot remove the watermark

Reference [YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#modestbranding)

> **modestbranding:** 
>   This parameter lets you use a YouTube player that does not show a YouTube logo. Set the parameter value to 1 to prevent the YouTube logo from displaying in the control bar. **Note that a small YouTube text label will still display in the upper-right corner of a paused video when the user's mouse pointer hovers over the player.**

Comment: This works, but now I'm stuck with the YouTube watermark in the bottom right. I tried setting modestbranding to 1 and showinfo to 0 in playerVars. Also, isn't it better to use iframe than div?

Comment: You are using an iframe which is not connect with the Youtube API. Basically YT Api creates iframe for you. the first parameter you gave to the constructor is the id of the iframe.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Do you know how to get rid of that YouTube watermark, though? I also need to either get rid of that still image it creates at the end, or fade it out before it happens.

Comment: Thank you very much, but unfortunately I still get the YouTube watermark, since I removed the controls. Please see my edited question for the playerVars I am using. I also want to fade before that still image shows up at the very end.

Comment: Yes thats what gets me too. Unfortunately you cannot remove watermark by using Youtube api. they only allow it by using the embedded iframe like you did previously.

Comment: Actually, the watermark is happening even on the iframe version, too. This is unfortunate....

Comment: Worst case scenario, I might be able to just put a masking div over it, as long as the video is tall enough to have the watermark land in unused space. I'm still wondering, though, do you know how to fade the video out before the final still image appears? Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Yes, see onPlayerStateChange function. you can put all of that logic here

Comment: I don't see how, considering how it is an event trigger. How can I say "fade out 2 seconds before this event triggers?" Anyway, I accepted your answer because you have been a tremendous help. Thank you.